# Control the Pandoc word document output size / test image sizes

Tags: image, pandoc

My client wants to convert markdown text to word and we'll be using Pandoc. However, we want to control malicious submissions (e.g., a Markdown doc with 1000 externally hosted images each being 10 MB) that can stress/break the server when attempting to produce the output.

options are to regex the image patterns in the Markdown and test their size (or even limit the number) or even disallow external images entirely, but I wonder if there's a way to abort Pandoc if the produced docx exceeds a certain size?

Or is there a simple way to get the images and test their size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandoc normally fetches the images while writing the output file, but you can take control of that by using a [Lua filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html) to fetch the images yourself. This allows to stop fetching as soon as the combined size of the images becomes too large.

```lua
local total_size_images = 0
local max_images_size = 100000  -- in bytes

-- Process all images
function Image (img)
  -- use pandoc's default method to fetch the image contents
  local mimetype, contents = pandoc.mediabag.fetch(img.src)
  -- check that contents isn't too large
  total_size_images = total_size_images + #contents
  if total_size_images > max_images_size then
    error('images too large!')
  end
  -- replace image path with the hash of the image's contents.
  local new_filename = pandoc.utils.sha1(contents)
  -- store image in pandoc's "mediabag", so it won't be fetched again.
  pandoc.mediabag.insert(new_filename, mimetype, contents)
  img.src = new_filename
  -- return the modified image
  return img
end
```

Please make sure to read the section ["A note on security"](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#a-note-on-security) in the pandoc manual before publishing the app.

Comment: wow, this is so useful to know, I marked the answer as accepted as it's the thing I want to do. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to hear, you're welcome! I just remembered that some of the relevant behavior is a somewhat recent change, so you may have to update to the latest pandoc version.